# My Java Google Endpoints V2 project is throwing com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigException. What am I missing?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am seeing below error in logs. What would explain it?

I have another similar project that is working fine. I have gone over my pom.xml, web.xml, appengine-web.xml multiple times and cannot see what is missing.

This was previously a V1 project. Does that enter in?

Thanks in advance.

```
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyLogger warn: 
    Failed startup of context c.g.a.r.j.AppEngineWebAppContext@57e008cd
    {/, file:///base/data/home/apps/s~form8949/
     20171214t103140.406216052512279215/,UNAVAILABLE} (JettyLogger.java:29)
 com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigException: 
     Failed to fetch default config version for service
     'form8949.appspot.com'. No versions exist!
 at com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigSupplier.
    fetchLatestServiceVersion(ServiceConfigSupplier.java:157)
 at com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigSupplier.
    fetch(ServiceConfigSupplier.java:126) ...
```

2018 08 01 Addition per request:

Removing the below from my web.xml file silenced the error. 
Unfortunately, I still don't understand the reasons and the implications of doing so.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Did you solve this ? I have a similar issue and have problem solving it

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a strict migration and not needing the features in the Endpoints UI in Cloud Console, then you did some extra steps. You don't need the config or control filter. See the [migration steps](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating).

Comment: what if we do need the API management features? How would you make the error go away while retaining the filters?